# How do I setup ElasticSearch and Searchkick on my Nitrous.io box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, nitrousio, searchkick

I've added the searchkick gem to my GEMFILE and I also installed ElasticSearch 1.0 with Autoparts.  I'm still getting a connection refused message though when I attempt to reindex one of my models.  I'm thinking it is possibly because my elasticsearch server hasn't been started.  I'm unsure how to start it though on Nitrous.io.  Below is the command I'm attempting to run and the error message I'm receiving...

**Command**

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Player
```

**Result**

```
rake aborted!
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So as silly as this is... I just thought to try and type `elasticsearch` in my Console of Nitrous.io and that command started my elasticsearch server and then I was able to proceed.  Thanks to anyone that had looked into the issue with me!